# How to get to the original Fragment from Bottom Navigation View?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

I am facing a challenge in the app that i am developing.

I have a `BottomNavigationView` with 4 Fragments:

`Home Feed Notification Profile`

Home is the home fragment of my `NAV GRAPH`.

Lets suppose Home has a button and on click of it, it goes to CartFragment. Now i click to Feed by using `BottomNavigationView`. So now, when i click on home fragment again from `BottomNavigation` view...i see the `CartFragment` whereas i want to see the `HomeFragment`. And it doesn't even show the `HomeFragment` tab active on the bottomNavigationView, it is like it completely replaces it.

I am not able to switch to my original fragment whenever i click on a tab from `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reset your backstack when you press one of the bottom nav items, use below code where you define bottom nav view and this will solve your problem:

```
        yourBottomNavView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            NavigationUI.onNavDestinationSelected(item, yourNavController)
            yourNavController.popBackStack(item.itemId, inclusive = false)
            true
        }
```

Just change yourBottomNavView and yourNavController with yours.